# merge two text files using bash scripts in linux

Tags: linux, bash, text, merge

I have two text files. the first one looks like this:

```
a  
b  
c
```

another file looks like this:

```
1 2   
3 4
```

I want to use bash scripts in Linux to merge these two files so that each row of the first file will be placed next to all the rows of the second file and output looks like this:

```
a 1 2    
a 3 4  
b 1 2  
b 3 4  
c 1 2  
c 3 4
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far ? It seems like something that could easily be done with 2 imbricated `while read` loops, or an awk script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[++n]=$0; next} {for (i in a) print $0, a[i]}' file2 file1

a 1 2
a 3 4
b 1 2
b 3 4
c 1 2
c 3 4
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In pure shell, you can simply do:

```
#Usage: the_script FirstFile SecondFile
while read -r l1; do
    while read -r l2 ; do
        echo "$l1 $l2"
    done <"$2"
done <"$1"
```

but the files better not be large, because the shell reads aren't very efficient (they make a syscall for each byte).

Answer (score 0):

try one more awk where it will give output in same order as Input_file1.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {c[++k]=$0} END{for(q=1;q<=i;q++){for(u=1;u<=k;u++){print a[q],c[u]}}}'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably be downvoted *mercilessly*, but I believe that these kind of tasks are better suited to `Perl` or `Python.`
Here's a `Python 2` solution:

```
$ cat 1col.tmp
a
b
c

$ cat 2col.tmp
1 2
3 4

$ cat merge.py
with open("1col.tmp") as col1f:
    for c1 in col1f.readlines():
        with open("2col.tmp") as col2f:
            for c2 in col2f.readlines():
                print c1.strip(), c2.strip()

$ python merge.py
a 1 2
a 3 4
b 1 2
b 3 4
c 1 2
c 3 4
```