# Ubuntu how to combine multiple text files into one with terminal

Tags: file, ubuntu, text, terminal, nano

I want to combine  multiple text files into one text file. Is there any command in ubuntu terminal to do this, or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge two text files using bash scripts in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368766/merge-two-text-files-using-bash-scripts-in-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `cat` like

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > outputFile
```

`cat` stands for concatenation.

`>` is for [output redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

If `outputFile` already has something in it and you wish to append to it the contents of other files, use

```
cat file1 file2 file3 >> outputFile
```

as `>` would erase the old contents of `outputFile` if it already existed.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969641/append-one-file-to-another-in-linux) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much had no idea it was that easy